# How to access variables set in res.render() from within a dynamic helper function in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to create a dynamicHelper in Express.js.  Is it possible to access the variables set in res.render from within the dynamicHelper? In particular I want to be able to access the variable 'title'. The only option I could think of was to attach the data I wanted to either the req or res object and access it from within the dynamicHelper that way.  However, I was wondering if it was already accessible some other way?

The following code shows the current structure of res.render(). Since the variable 'title' is built on the results a database call, one could equally ask the question of how to access the results of the database query from within a dynamicHelper?

```js
exports.viewContact = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  // Get document from DB.
  var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact');
  Contact.findOne({ _id: id}, function(err, results) {
    var breadcrumb = theme.breadcrumb({ path: url.parse(req.url).path, title: results.surname + ', ' + results.given_name });
    res.render('viewContact', {
      locals: {
        title: results.surname + ', ' + results.given_name,
        surname: results.surname,
        givenName: results.given_name,
        org: results.org,
        phones: results.phone,
        emails: results.email,
        addresses: results.address,
        breadcrumb: breadcrumb
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible to access local variables in other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have reworded my question since I fear it may have caused confusion.  In my question I am not referring to 'local variables' in a programming sense, but rather to variables attached to the 'locals' object being passed to res.render().